# Stata looping that I can't comprehend

Tags: stata

I learned that to change lower case variable names to upper case variables I need to do the following:

```
foreach var of varlist * {
  rename `var' `=upper("`var'")'
}
```

But I can't comprehend how this can really work.

First, `rename` does not require `=`  to change variable names.

Second, I understand that I need to embrace `var` with ` and '

But what does that ` and ' mean surrounding

`=upper("var'")`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that. You don't need a loop and you don't need that syntax. Consider

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ds
make          mpg           headroom      weight        turn          gear_ratio
price         rep78         trunk         length        displacement  foreign

. rename *, upper

. ds
MAKE          MPG           HEADROOM      WEIGHT        TURN          GEAR_RATIO
PRICE         REP78         TRUNK         LENGTH        DISPLACEMENT  FOREIGN
```

Otherwise you are puzzled at the

```
`= '
```

because indeed that is nothing to do with `rename`. That syntax obliges Stata to evaluate a scalar expression on the fly so that `rename` sees only the result of that expression. In your case the string expression

```
upper("`var'")
```

yields an upper-case version of the variable name contained in local macro `var`.

This syntax is documented at `help macro` and `[P] macro` (e.g. 
[in this version](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pmacro.pdf) p.13) as one kind of expansion operator.

All that said, all variable names upper case is horrible style....